# Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7, display-resolution

Environment: Lenovo T530 running Windows 7.  Have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a virtual machine using VM Virtual Box.  Have installed all the updates from both Virtual Box and Ubuntu.

Problem: While in Ubuntu's desktop and other Ubuntu initiated programs, the window is reduced to about 3x4 inches showing in the middle of the rest of my regular Virtual Box window.  I am seeing only the upper right hand of the screen output of what I would normally see.

I've seen [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/q/22743/107450)

But, none of these answers works in 14.04.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. When installing the Guest Additions with Ubuntu 14.04 I get "Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed. Not installing"

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate _question_ (even if the _answer_ is the same). I found this only via searching about screen res problems, and learned here that "guest additions" is the answer. (If I already knew to ask about "guest additions", I wouldn't have had a question/problem.)

Comment: The answers aren't even the same. Generally you would use the guest additions iso that can be mounted from the host, but it seems to be specific for 14.04 that you must install via the apt repo for it to work properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot change screen size from 640x480 after 14.04 installation on VirtualBox OSX](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452108/cannot-change-screen-size-from-640x480-after-14-04-installation-on-virtualbox-os)

Comment: I've been having problems with this as well. Guest additions appears to have installed correctly but full screen mode still has a small os display. kraxor, where are you seeing system settings?

Comment: @BrianBarrick I had the same problem after installing the Guest Additions from the VB menu (Devices -> Install Guest Additions). But after explicitly running the command from the 1st answer below (sudo apt-get install ...) and restarting the VM, everything was Ok.

Comment: Simply go to System Settings -> Displays -> Scale for Menu and Title Bars )and adjust accordingly (after installing guest additions

Comment: I too got "Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed. Not installing" error, and none of the solutions here worked except updating Virtualbox to 5.0.8 (and getting latest extensions), then trying again and finally reboot (the guest).

Answer (score 266):

You basically need the Guest additions, log into the Virtual Machine to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Finally restart the VM to complete the installation.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood this step before I read your answer and thought I was supposed to install Guest Additions on the host machine. d'oh.

Comment: @symphonyblade: Those packages are meant to be installed on the Guest OS indeed.

Comment: Does this work for ubuntu 12 also?

Comment: @carter The same set of packages also exist for 12.04.5. Once installed you should be able to set higher resolutions manually (e.g 1600x1200)

Comment: Was enough for me to install just `virtualbox-guest-dkms`

Comment: That worked like butterfly ... easy solution like 123 .. Thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't work on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation. I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies: virtualbox-guest-x11: Depends: xorg-video-abi-15 Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)`

Comment: @Antonio I think you'd better write your own answer instead of editing an existing one. So far 1 user has approved your edit, but another has rejected it for deviating too much from the original content. The edit may get rejected all together.

Comment: @THelper I don't think you should install the x11 part. I suggest you take a look to [the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/595192/359343) I just posted.

Comment: If anyone runs into this comment: Use the answer with Devices -> Insert Guest Additions. Simple and works.

Comment: @THelper On ubuntu 14.04 I also got `The following packages have unmet dependencies.  virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-15...`. The solution by @conradk under [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/527077/103266) worked for me:
`sudo apt-get remove libcheese-gtk23`, then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core` and finally `sudo apt-get install -f virtualbox-guest-x11`

Comment: None of the solutions in the comments worked on 14.04.3 - I still had unmet dependencies.

Comment: I am unable to do this on my Umbuntu 14.04 install because my network requires a proxy. I am unable to set the proxy because the GUI tool to do so requires more screen space than 640x480. Nice little catch-22 there.

Comment: ...figured out how to set the proxy, but this still doesn't work. It looks like the virtualbox stuff is just incompatible with too much of 14.04.3's X stuff. The only solution I could find was to **use 15.10 instead**. Still can't change the resolution, but its 1024x768 now, so its at least usable.

Comment: Fails miserably on Ubuntu 14.04. You should probably revise or delete this answer.

Comment: This worked for me for one reboot of the machine, then it was back to small size forever.

Comment: The 2nd answer here worked for me with 14.04.3, this one didn't do it.

Comment: This didn't work for me at all.  Still a tiny screen.

Answer (score 86):

On virtualbox you have to install "Guest Additions". There is no need to set a resolution via Ubuntu settings. With your guest window in the foreground select from the top menu:

```
VirtualBox -> Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image
```

In Ubuntu open a terminal, navigate to cd folder (usually /media/VBOXADDITIONS*) and run

```
sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Note that you should have a working compiler gcc/g++

Comment: This fails with an error saying it looks like guest additions had been installed from a different installer or package.  The only solution is the answer saying to use apt-get to install the three packages.

Comment: Exactly the same here trying to install Xubuntu 14.04 64bit on VirtualBox. Installing Guest Additions from mounted CD image is not working - it breaks X Server installation. Instaling with apt-get from public repositories as advised by Sylvain works.

Comment: +1 This is the only solution that worked for me. As a preliminary step, it was very important to update the VirtualBox Manager to the latest version available. I have posted [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/595192/359343) a new answer with some additional details.

Comment: Though an error appeared that says guest additions has been installed from a different installer..etc do you want to continue,answer with a Yes , after it finishes reboot and it will work

Comment: This worked for me! Using VirtualBox 4.3.26 and Ubuntu 14.04 downloaded from osboxes.org

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, on win8...

Comment: worked for me on VirtualBox 5.0.8 r103449, xubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso image

Comment: +1 worked for me - Virtualbox 5.0.10 Mac

Comment: +1 Although the CD was mounted under /media/{username}/.. Ubuntu 14.4 LTS on Windows 7 VBox

Comment: The previous apt-get solution failed for me with Ubuntu 14.4 but this solution works for me with VirtualBox 5.0.16 and 5.0.17 Linux Guest Additions after I used the CD button to load the iso Guest Addition image. The script itself was detected automatically and ran after prompting.

Answer (score 58):

I had the same problem as you. I did these steps, maybe helps you too:

1. Go to System settings → Software and Updates → Additional drivers
2. Use x86 virtualization solutions...
3. After that reboot your VirtualBox

My VirtualBox is working perfectly.

Comment: Oh my gosh. After trying so many other things and wasting so much time, this easy solution did the trick.

Comment: Simple as 1,2,3 - works.

Comment: Verified on Ubuntu Mate 14.04.1

Comment: Setting this option seems to go ok on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation, (no error messages) but after the reboot I still have 640x480 resolution and no option to change it.

Comment: On a fresh image of 14.04.2 desktop (retrieved from osboxes.org), when I boot I'm in 640x480.  I then open System Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers.   There is no option to choose 'Use x86 virtualizations solutions'.  Is it simply hidden because of resolution?  Do I have to install the Guest Additions first?

Comment: Did not help for me

Comment: On my Unbuntu 14.04 LTS installation there is no "Software and Updates" under System Settings". I see two categories of stuff there, "Personal" and "Hardware". Perhaps there is a third category I'm not seeing because ... *my screen is too small*?

Comment: Indeed you don't see it at the bottom because your resolution is too small, but you can scroll down.

Comment: In my Additional Drivers both InnoTek options say "This device is not working."

Comment: Did not work here (ubuntu 14.04 VB 5.0.14)

Comment: @T.E.D. Try to enable workspaces to virtually enlarge your screen: System Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior -> Enable workspaces.  You can switch the workpaces with Ctrl+Alt+Cursor, so you can see everything (with moving the windows a bit).

Answer (score 34):

After having first tried installing the Guest additions, which didn't work, I found another solution elsewhere: [linuxbsdos.com](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2014/10/31/solutions-for-low-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu-14-0414-10-and-virtualbox/).

Use Xdiagnose from the Dashboard. Search for and launch Xdiagnose, then enable all the options under the Debug section. Click the Apply button, then close the window and restart the system.

That's what finally did the trick! Now I get 1024 x 768 resolution instead of 640 x 480.

I never uninstalled the Guest additions, so it might be I needed to take both these measures.

[image]

---------- EDIT ---------

I have come to realize that the solution described above is just a fallback, in case installing the Guest Additions failed for some reason. I have finally managed to successfully install them, and can now choose from a bigger range of resolutions in the display settings. Here is how I did it, after having tried all of the above.

One thing I had already tried earlier was

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

This is not enough in itself, but might be a necessary prerequisite for the following steps (of which some might not be necessary...).

1. Update Virtualbox to the latest version (currently 4.3.24)
2. In Terminal in the Guest system type:

```
    sudo apt-get install dkms
    sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant
    sudo m-a prepare
```

If you have no top menu in the Guest system, it's because you're in scale mode which causes it to be hidden. In that case, press 
<kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to toggle scale mode (where <kbd>Host</kbd> is <kbd>Right Control</kbd> by default)

3. In the Guest system, go to the top menu, and click Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD Image. This should mount the CD image.
4. In my case, Autostart worked, and the installation started with a prompt. If it doesn't autostart, you can do the following

```
    cd /media/<username>/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.10_93012
    sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Just be sure to replace <username> by the logged in user's username.

And then a restart, as JTIM pointed out...

Comment: Well, it _did_ enable 1024x768 for me, that's at least something.
It still doesn't allow me to set anything higher though, despite trying all the other solutions.

Comment: +1 Your solution solved it for me as well!

Comment: I got for an instant 1024x768 with the login, then a corrupted window pretty wide... But this was anyway the closest I could get to the solution

Comment: I got it to work at any resolution following [these steps](http://askubuntu.com/a/595192/359343).

Comment: Great update! I'm not sure all steps are necessary (dkms is already up-to-date if you first install virtual-guest-dkms), but it certainly worked for me! The virtual box window with Ubuntu now automatically scales to all resolutions. Oh, and I needed to exclude the virtualbox-guest-x11 in your first step.

Comment: and then a restart :)

Comment: I will personally recommend this solution!

Answer (score 24):

Developing from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/451825/359343), and in fact pretty well explained also in [this other post](https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/359343). (I really tried everything else posted here but it does not seem to work on my Windows 7 system)

**Preliminary steps:**

1. Make sure you have installed the [latest version of Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)(*). Be careful that if you ask Virtual Box to update to the latest version it might very likely declare being updated even if a newer version exists!
2. It might be a good idea to start from a clean distribution, creating a new virtual machine, install there Ubuntu (I allowed downloading updated packages from the network during installation), and cloning it before proceeding, so that if you have troubles you can avoid restarting from the very beginning.
3. Install `build-essential` and `linux-headers-generic` packages. Apparently, [it's also reccomended to install `dkms`](https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/359343), as *"Running DKMS in the guest OS will keep Guest Additions installed after a guest kernel update"*.

**How to:**

1. Start your virtual machine
2. On Virtualbox menu -> Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image...
3. From Ubuntu you should see a popup, allow the CD autorun to install the program. For me, like many times before, it said he could not find Linux headers but, this time, in the end everything went fine.
   If the autorun does not work,  open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), navigate to folder (usually `/media/VBOXADDITIONS*`) and run

   `sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
4. Shut down and then start again your virtual machine

---

<sub>(*) If, like me, with the new version of the Virtual Box you have trouble with network, take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dE_miWfvvU) (In short: use Bridged network, and select "allow VMs")</sub>

Comment: Excellent. Out of all the answers, this is the only one which worked for me, with Ubuntu 14.04.2 64 bit guest and Windows 7 host.

Comment: Awesome, this solution actually worked perfectly after trying many others! Thank you!

Comment: This did work after so many failure attempts.

Comment: Worked like a charm on my Windows 7 / Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit setup. Thank you.

Comment: Finally, something that actually worked!   :-)   Ubuntu 14.04 on Ubuntu 14.04 host.

Comment: I was lacking an entire version behind with my VBox (and it sayd it was up to date...)! Thanks for the tip, I'd empathize it even more!!!

Comment: I tried some of the solutions posted and this is the one that worked for me. host: Windows 10, Virtualbox 6.1, guest lubuntu 18 64bit. Everything works well now. thanks

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by installing the guest additions as explained in the other answers and jacking the amount of video RAM in the settings as shown. [image: MateConfig]

Comment: After several hours of try with all other options (installing guest addons, updates etc.) I realized that this is the problem..

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It should be the first thing that the user have to check! I waste half a day to trying to figure out how to fix it and tried a 1000 ways... Eventually, you saved my day, thanks!

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko I'm glad it worked for you as well!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, simple solution could be:

[image]

Comment: HAHA Worked like a charm!!! Did not install guest additions or jump through any other special hoops like other answers recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I remained stuck for several days in low screen resolution in a Ubuntu 14.04 guest running on VirtualBox 4.1 on Debian Wheezy. None of the most commonly suggested solutions (e.g. installing `virtualbox-guest-dkms`, installing guest additions) helped. Installing VirtualBox from the [official downloads page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) worked!

Answer (score -1):

To expand on what Sylvain Pineau said, typing the following command is much easier (wildcards are accepted with `apt-get`):

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox*
```

Comment: But it will install packages like `virtualbox-source`, `virtualbox-dbg` and older versions (such as virtualbox-2.2) depending on your ppa settings