# Installation of virtualbox-guest-dkms fails

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualbox, dpkg, dkms

Recently I installed Ubuntu into VirtualBox. The problem was that the resolution was really small and it stayed small even when I enlarge it by going to view → switch to full screen. I searched and found this solution:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

which fails with this error message:

```
File "/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/dkms_packages.py", line 98, in <module>
with apport.fileutils.make_report_file(report) as f: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'make_report_file'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/make.log for more information
```

Content of the log file:

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-guest-4.3.10 for kernel 3.19.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Mi 18. Nov 11:15:34 CET 2015
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.c: In function ‘VBoxGuestCommonGetHandledEventsLocked’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.c:82:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
     uint32_t u32AllowedGuestCaps = pSession->u32AquiredGuestCaps | (VMMDEV_EVENT_VALID_EVENT_MASK & ~pDevExt->u32AcquireModeGuestCaps);
     ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.c:2660:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
     uint32_t fGenFakeEvents = 0;
     ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.c: In function ‘VBoxGuestCommonIOCtl’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest.c:2807:9: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
         VBoxGuestHGCMCallInfoTimed *pInfo = (VBoxGuestHGCMCallInfoTimed *)pvData;
         ^
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/VBoxGuest2.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/GenericRequest.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/HGCMInternal.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/Init.o
/Init.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/PhysHeap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/SysHlp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/VMMDev.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemAllocExecVmArea’:

/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:194:9: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘map_vm_area’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
         if (!map_vm_area(pVmArea, PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC, &papPagesIterator))
         ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/io.h:200:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/realmode.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/acpi.h:33,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/fixmap.h:19,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/apic.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/smp.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/mmzone_64.h:10,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/mmzone.h:4,
                 from include/linux/mmzone.h:912,
                 from include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from include/linux/slab.h:14,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:72,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:31:
include/linux/vmalloc.h:115:12: note: expected ‘struct page **’ but argument is of type ‘struct page ***’
 extern int map_vm_area(struct vm_struct *area, pgprot_t prot,
            ^
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/initterm-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/mpnotification-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/process-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/semevent-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/semeventmulti-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/semfastmutex-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/semmutex-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/spinlock-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/thread-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/thread2-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/time-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/linux/RTLogWriteDebugger-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/r0drv/generic/semspinmutex-r0drv-generic.o
/common/alloc/alloc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/err/RTErrConvertFromErrno.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/err/RTErrConvertToErrno.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/log/log.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/log/logellipsis.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/log/logrel.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/log/logrelellipsis.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/log/logcom.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/log/logformat.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/RTAssertMsg1Weak.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/RTAssertMsg1Weak.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2Add.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2AddWeak.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2AddWeakV.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2Weak.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2WeakV.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/assert.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/misc/thread.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/string/RTStrCopy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/string/RTStrCopyP.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/string/RTStrCopyP.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/string/strformat.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/string/strformatrt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/string/strformattype.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/string/strprintf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/string/strtonum.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/table/avlpv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/time/time.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxguest/common/time/time.c: In function ‘VBoxGuest_RTTimeFromString’:
...
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxsf/dirops.c:129:29: error: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’
     sf_g = GET_GLOB_INFO(dir->f_dentry->d_inode->i_sb);
                             ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxsf/vfsmod.h:144:60: note: in definition of macro ‘GET_GLOB_INFO’
 # define GET_GLOB_INFO(sb)       ((struct sf_glob_info *) (sb)->s_fs_info)
                                                            ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxsf/dirops.c:135:16: error: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’
     inode = dir->f_dentry->d_inode;
                ^
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxsf/dirops.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build/vboxsf] Error 2
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/4.3.10/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic'
~
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to dump the logfile. This helps to keep the question clear.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/588943/experiencing-small-resolution-issue-in-ubuntu-14-04-2-with-virtualbox-getting-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve the problem. In my case, the problem was that I was running older VirtualBox and after updating it, the command virtualbox-guest-dkms worked and I could switch to full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this, which I prefer.

1. Open Terminal
2. `sudo apt-get update && upgrade -y`
3. Once complete run: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
4. On the running VirtualBox window along the top select Devices > Insert Guest addons cd image.
5. In your terminal navigate to: `cd /media/USERNAME/` and run `ls` to then see what the virtual disc is called in my case it is `VBOXADDITIONS_5.0.10_104061` and `cd` to it.
6. Now in the folder run `sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
7. Wait for it to finish
8. Reboot and Enjoy.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but I tried your steps but it did not work. After installing (devices->insert guest addons) and after running that batch file, I go the following message in response to those commands:The headers for the current running kernel were no gound, If the following module compilation fails then this could be the reason. And later I found this:
Not installing X Window System drivers