# Ubuntu screen size does not fit properly in my desktop computer monitor. It does not use the full monitor screen

Tags: display

I've just installed VirtualBox (version 5.0.14) and Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) in my Windows 7 (64 bits, Service Pack 1) desktop computer. Ubuntu works fine, however the screen size does not use 100 % of the computer screen.I mean a small Ubuntu screen was placed in the middle of the monitor, and actually I cannot reach some of the icons due to size screen limitation. 
Note: Under Ubuntu Settings/Display/Video tab I already configured 128 MB for the Video Memory.
Also I use NVIDIA GeForce9200.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To set resolution as 1366x768 for example:

Go to C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox and run the following command, then restart virtual machine:

```
VBoxManage.exe setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution 1366,768
```

This will set the resolution for all guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

I actually looked it up and possibly found your answer here

[cannot change screen size from 640x480 after 14.04 installation on VirtualBox OSX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452108/cannot-change-screen-size-from-640x480-after-14-04-installation-on-virtualbox-os)

All you need to do is update your virtual box
Go to the terminal, type:

```
    sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

restart the VM, and that should do