# Installing Guest Additions causing problems

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I am trying to install Guest Additions in VirtualBox with Windows XP host and Ubuntu 12.04 guest. I followed the above steps:

```
Devices-> Insert Guest Additions CD Image.
After that I locate the folder /media/VBoxAdditions4.3.4_91027/
and run sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

I want to be able to create shared folders and adjust the resolution of the screen. I achieved to do the first issue, but I couldn't do the second one. I didn't get any message, however it is not possible to change the resolution of the screen and I cannot switch to fullscreen. What am I doing wrong?

I found in the instal log the following message: `unknown version of the X Window System`. I've tried the solution of the proposed link but I got the following message:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
                    Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried also to install with the command `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms` but nothing is changing. During the installation of dkms I got the message: `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel 3.13.0-32-generic(i686).`

Comment: I ve already track this, tried it, but didnt work!

Comment: It is a dupe. The package error is another issue that you may fix [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/62483).

Comment: @Lucio - This is not even close to a dup. This question is about a specific situation that happens on a fresh Umbutu install. That question is about cleaning up a package database that *has become messed up*. This question is about dealing with a base install with a display that is too small to be usable, that question's answers suggest using the GUI. It answers are simply not usable to answer this question.

Comment: I am really surprised that this question got closed as duplicate of *those* ones.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Update

It seems that [conradk](https://askubuntu.com/users/45024/conradk) solution is working so I'll post it here in the answer as well.

- I did `sudo apt-get remove libcheese-gtk23`, then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core` and finally `sudo apt-get install -f virtualbox-guest-x11`. It solved problems for me

Scroll down and give him a vote up if this works for you.

---

I looked up your problem on google and this is what I found.

Just running the below will take care of installing the package and all its dependencies. However, it seems to be taking some time for it to complete, so be ready for a long wait.

### Fix:

```
$ sudo apt-get -q -y -f build-dep virtualbox-ose-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms
```

This will install all dependencies for 'packagename' so it can build it.

After the building has completed just install it again by typing:

```
$ sudo apt-get -q -y -f install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms
```

You can read about the options for apt-get with `$ man apt-get`.

### References

1. [Ubuntu The following packages have unmet dependencies: $package1 : Depends: $package2 but it is not going to be installed](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.se/2013/05/ubuntu-following-packages-have-unmet.html)

Comment: I ve tried your solution. However I am getting crash report problem occurred while installing software. Package virtualbox-guest-dkms. After that I am unable to boot to VM.

Comment: What does the crash report say? I'm currently not at home to try this myself. I will look into this some more once I am home.

Comment: Does not work for 14.04.2: E: Unable to find a source package for virtualbox-ose-guest-utils

Comment: I did `sudo apt-get remove libcheese-gtk23`, then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core` and finally `sudo apt-get install -f virtualbox-guest-x11`. It solved problems for me.

Comment: @conradk you sir are a life saver! None of the blogs/posts/answers solved it, then looking at your little tiny comment did it for me. I want to buy you a beer!

Comment: Awesome ! If someone is reading this and the above doesn't work, what I'd try is to remove all packages that are said to be broken by `apt-get` one by one. In my case, the first broken package was `libcheese-gtk23`, which is why I chose to remove that one. Seemed like it worked out fine :-)

Comment: @conradk This finally did the trick for me, thanks! Though, afterward I noticed that I couldn't access System Settings anymore - I'm not sure if removing libcheese was the cause, but it might've set off a chain uninstall. I fixed that by installing `unity-control-center` as it was apparently not installed. Everything looks good now.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I faced the exact same problem as OP faced. and @conradk comment saved my day!!

Comment: After installing these three items, sudo apt-get remove libcheese-gtk23; 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core;sudo apt-get install -f virtualbox-guest-x11; I got resolution problem fixed, but my ubuntu desktop is blank and I can not do anything.

Comment: @conradk, can post your answer here? You'll get a bunch of upvotes - http://askubuntu.com/questions/650094/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-02-and-virtualbox I want to offer you a bounty!

Comment: @ArulxZ: I would, but it seems like your question is really a duplicate of the question right here. So it would make more sense to flag it as a duplicate so we avoid duplicating answers.

Comment: This solution did work for VirtualBox 5, Host windows 10, Guest Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: The @conradk solution allowed me to install virtualbox-guest-x11, but I am not getting automatic desktop resizing as I expected when I resize the console window. This is with 14.04.3.

Comment: was able to install virtualbox-guest-x11 but my screen is still small.

Comment: After installing as above, sometimes the desktop doesnt give option for system settings, then use  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`  or use `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`