# Resolution issue with Ubuntu 14.04 on virtualbox 4.3.28

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, display-resolution

I have installed virtualbox 4.3.28 on windows 8 64 bit. I installed ubuntu 14.04 lts b3 bit on it.

I am having low resolution problem in it. I followed many blogs and forums but no luck till now.

I followed this [page](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/virtualbox-and-the-latest-14-04-display-stuck-at-low-resolution/), I installed virtualbox guest package by this command `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms` but there is not changes after re-starting virtual machine.

Then I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451805/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-virtualbox) but no luck.

Lastly I followed [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526995/installing-guest-additions-causing-problems). It fixed the resolution but after re-start I got blank screen. No Icons on the screen nor shortcuts are working.

I want a final solution to fix lower resolution problem, there are many answers available but no one is working for me. If somebody has solution for the particular environment then please post.

This question should not be marked duplicate, if someone votes for duplicate then he/she should provide the solution for this particular scenario.