# Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04.02 and VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, command-line, virtualbox, display-resolution

I am trying to change screen resolution of Ubuntu 14.04.02 running in VirtualBox. I tried to install [Guest additions packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/451879/239913) but I'm getting this error -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-15
Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-core`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that other folks have had the same sort of issue. I found a thread with lots of workarounds and solutions on this very site. I hope this helps.

[Same issues with fixes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451805/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-virtualbox)

Comment: The answer in the link doesn't work. That's why I posted this question. Read the question carefully.