# Visual GUI no keyboard/mouse input possible

Tags: 16.04, xorg, input, guest-additions

I think I somehow broke my visual GUI of my ubuntu-16.04.3 LTS. It does not accept neither keyboard nor mouse interaction anymore (and doesn't show the mouse pointer at all).

I'm running the OS inside a virtualbox, but that doesn't seem to bee the problem, since I was able to start the system with advanced options without a gui. (start 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-38-generic (upstart) )

first error message after login:

> [  11.155750] systemd-logind[1463]: Failed to enable subscription: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
>
> [ 11.155779] system-logind[1463]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Input/output error

Now the last things I tried to do before this happened was to install virtualbox-guest-x11, and because that didn't work initially, also xserver-xorg-core as
recommended here: [Installing Guest Additions causing problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526995/installing-guest-additions-causing-problems)

After rebooting, the problems started.

Anyone knows what I did wrong? I could just install a new VM since I have all important files saved, but I don't want to reinstall all my programms...

Comment: How did you re-install given that your keyboard and mouse are not working? I am in the same boat as yours. I am unable to access some important files I've been working on over the past few months.

Comment: Reviewers: I do not understand why this would be considered a problem that cannot be reproduced. The solution was [to reinstall some specific packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/973844/22949). Presumably this may work for other users if they encounter the same situation. It's not like the OP rebuilt the virtual machine or otherwise reinstalled the whole OS.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I solved it. I just reinstall the xorg-stuff, as shown here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-removeinstall-and-reconfigure-xorg-without-reinstalling-ubuntu.html

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Everything works fine again.