# Resize of VirtualBox Resolution Doesn't Work

Tags: virtualbox

I've recently installed the Guest Additions CD on my windows VirtualBox running Ubuntu 14.04. It was working great for a while - screen resized automatically, etc.

However, when I turned off my host computer and restarted it today, the resolution suddenly reverted back to its pre-Guest Additions CD state. However, when I try to re-install the CD, it says it is already loaded.

Does anyone know if there is another way to get the screen back to resize?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and VirtualBox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451805/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-virtualbox). Try the first answer where guest additions are installed using a package manager.

Comment: @SylvainPineau THANK YOU! The link you provided worked wonders! :)