# Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and VMware

Tags: 14.04, resolution, vmware, vmware-player

Yesterday I faced a similar problem with the one presented here: [Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451805/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-virtualbox)
 only that I was having the issue in VMware.

I provided the answer there but **Sylvain Pineau** suggested that I should ask the same question and answer it myself.

That's what I will do below...

Comment: If the other answers won't work try to increas video card memory in the VM settings. It worked for me.

Comment: You have to edit the video card to set the amount of memory.  That allows you to select the resolution you want and will auto populate the memory field.    The hint was https://askubuntu.com/questions/545536/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-vmware# it says 8M but that will not work for todays highest resolution settings.

Answer (score 7):

My configuration is host : windows 7 and vmware guest : ubuntu 14.04.
For long time I've seen if I update the vmplayer or some software in vmplayer that screws my display and then in full screen it can no longer capture host display.So today I just followed the instruction provided in this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) and fixed it without installing any additional software.I hope it helps other.

At first run :

```
$ xrandr -q

tanay@ubuntu:~$ xrandr -q Screen 0: minimum 1 x 1, current 1904 x 1070, maximum 8192 x 8192 Virtual1 connected primary 1904x1070+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm    800x600       
60.0 +   60.3      2560x1600      60.0      1920x1440      60.0      1856x1392      60.0      1792x1344      60.0      1920x1200      59.9  1600x1200      60.0      1680x1050      60.0      1400x1050      60.0  1280x1024      60.0      1440x900       59.9      1280x960       60.0  1360x768       60.0      1280x800       59.8      1152x864       75.0  1280x768       59.9      1024x768       60.0      640x480        59.9  1904x1070_75.00   74.9*  Virtual2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual7 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Then you can see which output is connected,here Virtual1 is connected.
Then guess a good resolution for your screen.For me I guessed following configuration.

```
Eg:cvt <horizontal length> <vertical length> <refresh rate>

$ cvt 1900 1070 75
```

The output is

```
# 1904x1070 74.87 Hz (CVT) hsync: 83.85 kHz; pclk: 216.00 MHz Modeline "1904x1070_75.00"  216.00  1904 2040 2240 2576  1070 1073    1083 1120
-hsync +vsync
```

Then you need to copy the text after "Modelline" and paste that in following command like the example below

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1904x1070_75.00"  216.00  1904 2040 2240 2576  1070 1073 1083 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then take the screen resolution details from the quote and use it in next command.For me the command is

```
$ xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1904x1070_75.00
```

The next command to set it in ubuntu for me is

```
$ xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1904x1070_75.00
```

If the last command doesn't work for you,you can go back to ubuntu display gui setting and can chose the display you have added just now.For me the option was 1904 x 1070 (16:9)

However if you are fine with this experiment and have found the desired screen resolution and to make that permanent,write the all the last 3 commands starting from xrandr --newmode command in your .xprofile file using following command and then save,exit and restart your ubuntu vm and you will get your desired resolution permanently.

```
$ gedit ~/.xprofile
```

Answer (score 4):

**Symptom:**

Each time you start/restart a virtual machine in VMware it starts in low resolution initially. Then, once you switch to full screen the resolution goes to full-screen (given that VMware tools are installed previously)

**Solution:**

When the VMware starts in small screen, do not switch to full-screen mode.

1. Go to `Displays` settings within your Ubuntu 14.04 Guest: `System Settings` -> `Displays`, then try to switch to
   the desired resolution from the drop-down menu.
2. If the screen is too small to press the `Apply` button, make sure
       that your current selection is at the drop-down menu with the
       desired resolution.
3. Now, press `Tab` key in your keyboard `7` times, this should have
       brought your selection to the `Apply` button.
4. Press `Enter`

This worked for me, hope works for the others as well.

Comment: What display settings are you referring to?  Host or Guest?

Comment: Guest; added to the answer.

Comment: That is not possible with the guest OS.  see [Here](https://copy.com/K2yq1yshtPHn2R6R).  If you mean from the host OS, I don't think that it works.  Can you supply a image of that?  Thanks

Comment: If I got you right, I see where the confusion is. I meant Display settings within the VM, not the Display settings of the VM itself. I modified the answer to it fits better

Comment: @KristofTak the resolution support is partly due to VMware tools - I've made it work after installing the tools.  My Lubuntu VMs all now support screen resolution changes in VMware Workstation

Comment: @ThomasW. When I was facing the problem I could also use any resolution once I switched to full-screen and with VMware tools installed, however the frustrating part was that each time the VM was re-/started it would initiate in 800x600 resolution and destroy mu icons layout. At least now I can preserve the layout as the VM starts at the desired resolution

Comment: @KristofTak It still does that for the logon screen for mt Lubuntu VM - it then uses the config I had set up and saved in the user's settings after login...

Comment: Instead of tapping TAB 7 times... if you don't see the whole window with all of its buttons, press ALT and click on any non-typing area in the window and you can drag it until you see all the necessary buttons (like Apply and Cancel in this example).
This "trick" works for all types of windows and is a general and handy feature in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.profile` with the commands doesn't work and all reverted back to the original setup.

However, if you place these lines into your `.bashrc`, these will take effect when you fire up a terminal from the original window.

Answer (score 0):

Problem : Display / Flicker issue in the VMware Ubuntu installation

I had this problem as well. The Problem is not with Ubuntu installation, its the VM ware settings for a particular image which can create this issue

To fix it I went to settings for VMware Workstation>> select the machine >> right click >> virtual machine settings >>Display >> and disabled the 3D Graphics checkbox.

Just reboot the machine.

After this it was fine.