# Trying virtual machines, installing guest additions causes extremely small resolution

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution

When I install Ubuntu via VirtualBox, I can only have resolution of 640x480 or something similar. I found that I needed to install guest additions to get more resolution choices. Doing this makes my Ubuntu look like this in VM window:

[image]

I obviously can't navigate in this window and was wondering what my next course of action should be.

Comment: I remember that after installing Guest Auditions, I had the same problem. I reinstalled the Guest Auditions, again, and it work, but have no idea why. Please try reinstalling, maybe it's the same problem.

Comment: I have tried to reinstall, but I get a mounting error and nothing happens. How did you reinstall? I cannot do it thru terminal because I cannot see anything in the GUI ...I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Ubuntu build and reinstalling additions but it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Does switching to other terminals work Ctrl - Alt - F4 ?

Comment: Did you select *Auto Resize* HOST + G and *Adjust Window Size* HOST + A in the Virtual Box *View* settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal: CTRL+ALT+T

Install these Guest Additions Packages:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Make sure you put your sudo user password and packages are installed correctly.
After that installation is Done. Restart your VM

If the problem still stays...
Try:

```
Go to System settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional drivers
Use x86 virtualization solutions...
After that reboot your virtual box
```

Source: [Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451805/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-virtualbox)

After doing this if you still have the same resolution:

Open Terminal CTRL+ALT+T (Hotkey) type in terminal:

```
xrandr -s 1024x768
```

It will set your screen resolution to 1024x768

Comment: I cannot do that because I cannot navigate the ui. Perhaps uninstall and do that before installing additions?

Comment: Tried the above answer, still does not work. Just the window is not as small now. http://i.imgur.com/QfA7vjy.jpg

Comment: Open Terminal CTRL+ALT+T (Hotkey) type in terminal: xrandr -s 1024x768

Comment: Can't access terminal because screen resolution auto resizes to smaller resolution.

Comment: just type: ctrl+alt+t (it will open terminal) then type the command i have written and press enter and tell me what it does..(you dont have to see anything)

Comment: It does nothing. Tried multiple times.

Comment: OK. I Have found a possible solution open terminal (CTRL + ALT +T): sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11

Type this command make sure you put in your user password to get these packages installed. after that installation is finished. Restart VM.

Comment: After that installation of packages are finished restart your machine: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11

Comment: I made the EDIT try installing those packages I have told you and tell me if problem still stays..

Comment: Nope. I tried everything. VM window looks the exact same as the first picture I posted. It only does this after installing additions. But I don't want 640x480 either so.

Also it just defaults to automatic window resizing and that makes the resolution extremely small and I cannot recover from it. The only thing that 'fixes' this issue is reinstalling Ubuntu and starting over.

Comment: Okay, xrandr -s 1024x768 now works. strange. Will keep updated.

edit: tried other resolutions and they did not work, now 1024x768 does not work. From what i can sort of read in the terminal, it says it is not an available mode...

Comment: After getting lucky and being able to reinstall guests additions via devices tab, i have many more resolution choices in Ubuntu. This has been very odd, thanks for your help dude.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, set it to answered in comments.