# How can I merge four workspaces into one? Ubuntu on OS X using Virtual Box

Tags: 14.04, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I have installed Virtual Box on Mac OS X Yosemite version 10.10.1. Then installed Ubuntu Desktop version 14.04.1. The problem is that I found the Ubuntu's desktop split into 4 workspaces which I  have to switch between. Each workspace is not enough to display a whole application window. for example, when I open system settings; the window is bigger than the upper left workspace.

Is there a way to see the entire desktop without  being split into workspaces?

Comment: Install VirtualBox Guest Additions and then try changing the resolution of your Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Set view--> auto resize display option in virtual box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can configure Ubuntu to only have one workspace by going to <kbd>System settings</kbd> - <kbd>Appearance</kbd> - <kbd>Behaviour</kbd> - <kbd>Enable Workspaces</kbd>.

Yes, you can configure the screen resolution of your virtual box by following this thread: [Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451805/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-virtualbox)

No, you cannot have your cake and eat it too!  ;-)