# Problem with screen resolution on virtual box ubuntu14.04

Tags: graphics, virtualbox, resolution, radeon

I have got problem with screen resolution. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.01 on virtual box and try to change screen resolution to FullHD. Right now I have got something like ~1330x680. How can I change it to FullHD. I tried settings display, but there the biggest resolution is "~1330x680". I also tried install:

```
sudo apt-get install purge fglrx
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

But it didn't help. I installed virtual box on desktop and then istall Ubuntu 14.04.01. I have got processor intel i3 and graphics card radeon 7970. Please tell me how can I solve it. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and VirtualBox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451805/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-virtualbox)

Answer (score 0):

Just virtualbox-guest-dkms is not enough.
In the link below they suggest also `sudo apt-get install  virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11`