# Virtual Box Resolution Stuck at 640 x 480

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I am running Windows 8, and Ubuntu 14.04.2. I need step by step instructions on how to install guest additions. Be very clear if you are referring to the host or guest.

I saw another fix to run the x86 version of the guest additions through Linux, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Which machine is your host? Is Win8 running Ubuntu or the other way around?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451805/screen-resolution-problem-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-virtualbox

Comment: Is Ubuntu the host and Windows in the VM, or the other way around?

Comment: Sorry for the not clarifiicarion, Windows is running Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an hard time using the terminal. 
Don't worry it's quite simple, just follow those steps:

1. Start the machine
    [image]
2. Now, on the top menu, go on Devices and click Insert Guest Additions CD image ...
3. In Ubuntu 15.04 you can just run it, it does everything by itself. If it doesn't, follow those steps.
4. Open the terminal from the launcher [image]
5. Write  `cd /media/$USER/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.26_98988`  (if the name of the CD is different, check it in Files) and press Enter.
6. Now, write  `sudo ./runasroot.sh`  and press enter.
   [image]
7. Insert the password and press enter

Done. It should work fine and without any efforts.

Comment: Thank you, trying it now. I have one question. What program/theme is your windows outline, such as the exit and minimize buttons?

Comment: It worked, thank you for the help! And in step 3 I think you meant 14.04, not 15.04 because it ran for me automatically on 14.04.2

Comment: And it seems to always be a 4:3 ration, while my screen dimensions are 1366 x 768, is there an override or setting?

Comment: Can you post a screen? It's set at 4:3 even in fullscreen? Did you enabled 3D acceleration and gave 128mb of video memory to the system?

Comment: Thanks, forgot to set the memory and 3D acceleration. Is there any tips you can give me for minimizing host use (Win 8) to save processing power for the guest (Ubuntu)?

Comment: Give more memory and cpu usage at the machine from the settings. Be careful with CPU/RAM usage! :) If the answer helped you, please mark that as Accepted.

Comment: @DarioSalvati I've looked at lots of solutions, even installed guest additions through Ubuntu, and your solution was the only one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

@Dario-salvati mentioned most things with an easy way. I want to add some points also:
Guest addition that comes with Ubuntu is not newer than Virtualbox's own guest pack. However Guest CD doesn't include "Virtualbox-guest-dkms" , thats what i realized earlier. You'll see that you can't choose it from Sources. But if you apply

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms -y
```

than it will automatically install the missing package from Ubuntu international repo and you could choose this driver after a restart.

Also you should go to Virtualbox machine settings and give at least **2GB RAM**, 128 MB VRAM and enable 3D acceleration. This will solve your problem exactly, if you have further question, you can comment this post.

(i use this specs on my 16.04 and there is no problem with graphical or resulution issue, i even used dual screen with my monitor.)