# Cannot change screen resolution for 14.04.3 in Virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

Have tried to change the resolution the following command: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms`.

But it did not work. Error given: `virtualbox-guest-x11 depends xorg-video-abi-15.`

Googled for answers and one of the recommendations is to run the following:
`sudo apt-get -q -y -f build-dep virtualbox-ose-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms`.

This did not work either. Desperate for help :-)

Comment: This may be an issue from an old Virtual Box release. What version is your host, guest and of Virtual Box? Update if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screen Resolution Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and VirtualBox](http://askubuntu.com/q/451805/267752)

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the resolution using xrandr.

**WARNING!** Make sure you enter into a tty console (outside of lightdm),
or else it will mostly cause errors in the x server. (Use
Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2/F3/etc.)

Now, use these commands:

```
xrandr --fb [enter width here]x[enter height here] --display [display number, default: 0]
sudo service lightdm restart
```

These lines of commands will make the X server to reboot and they will change the display resolution to your desired resolution.

Hope this helps! Peace,
matemate01

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use an older version of VirtualBox ... instead use the current version VirtualBox 5.0 :

Uninstall the old version of VirtualBox

```
sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"
```

Remove leftovers in case there are any

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Download and register the ORACLE public key

```
wget -q -O - https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the ORACLE VirtualBox repository to the software sources

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-vbox.list
```

Update the software repositories

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install VirtualBox 5.0

```
sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-5.0
```

Download the [Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Open VirtualBox Preferences and add the extension pack.

It is recommended to restart the operating system afterwards.

**Note for other users reading this answer, in case they use another Ubuntu edition as 14.04 :**

You have to replace `trusty` with the Ubuntu edition you are using when adding the repository !

As of Ubuntu 16.04 the ORACLE public key to download and register has  changed :

`oracle_vbox.asc` has to be replaced with `oracle_vbox_2016.asc` !